# Trying to set only time in UIDatePicker in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I am trying to set the UIDatePicker to come up with the time only.  The DatePicker comes up through an action when the textfield is pressed.  I have not used the DatePicker Viewer.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

```
let starttimedatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    startTimeDiveTextField.inputView = starttimedatePicker
    starttimedatePicker.addTarget(self, action: "startTimeDiveChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)


func startTimeDiveChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    startTimeDiveTextField.text = formatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}
```

Comment: Have you read the docs for `UIDatePicker`? Please look at the `datePickerMode` property.

Comment: ... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/datePickerMode

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try setting its Mode:

```
starttimedatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
```

Comment: Damn, knew it was something easy.  Not a good way to start the new year.  Thanks

Comment: You might wanna set it as the answer so it can help other people as well. I am glad I could help! :)

Comment: Sorry, not enough coffee today

Answer (score 6):

This may help you.

```
let starttimedatePicker = UIDatePicker()
starttimedatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
startTimeDiveTextField.inputView = starttimedatePicker
starttimedatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.startTimeDiveChanged), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)


func startTimeDiveChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    startTimeDiveTextField.text = formatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}
```

If you are using DatePicker in Storyboard or Xib then set like this.

[image]