# Swift3- How to get only time from UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift3, uidatepicker

I'm trying to create an alarm clock app for iOS, Im new to Swift. I want to know how to get only the time from  the UIDatePicker. Till now, I have a code which just gives the entire date with time. 
`import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var alarmTime: UIDatePicker!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func alarmTime(_ sender: UIDatePicker){
 sender.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
    print(sender.date)
}
```

}
`
[Here is the screenshot of the output of the above code in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmSyu.png)

Comment: show your tried code, show this **have a code which just gives the entire date with time**

Comment: you need to format your dateformatter .

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Here is my IBAction func for date picker. For now I just made it as simple as to just print the set time.  ` @IBAction func alarmTime(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
       // alarmTime.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
        print(alarmTime.date)
    }
`

Comment: @ReshmaSuresh - you are in the right way, just show the code

Comment: @KKRocks Can you brief me a little?

Comment: try this `sender.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time print(sender.date)` and print once what the result you get in console

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34559224/3901620

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Still it prints the date along with the time.

Comment: @ReshmaSuresh - can you show the output

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I've edited my question with the screenshot of the output, could you have look?

Comment: create reference outlet of your piker then set `yourButton.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time`

Answer (score 6):

Set your date picker mode as below.

`datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time`

**Get Time from Date :**

```
    let date = Date()

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let comp = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
    let hour = comp.hour
    let minute = comp.minute
```

Comment: Yeah, I set. But still it print with the date

Comment: @ReshmaSuresh add the code to get the time from date

Comment: Its an IBAction, so each time i change the time in the picker i want it to be printed.

Comment: Whenever value changed you are getting the date right.. Convert that date into time and then update the ui

Comment: +1, works for me to getting hours and date, but it will be better use hour and minute attributes with unwrapping in your answer, cause of components hour and minute are optional

Answer (score 4):

```
 let datePicker = UIDatePicker()  
  datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
// datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
  txtFildDeadLine.textField.inputView = datePicker
```

> And according to your question, place it in viewDidLoad

```
alarmTime.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. But it still prints the date.

Comment: update your question with code which you have tried.

Comment: Yeah, I updated, could you just have look?

Comment: create reference outlet of your piker then set `yourButton.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time`

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: Its an action, so each time when i change in the picker I want it to be printed, idk why it just prints it along with the date even though i set the mode to time

Comment: remove `sender.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time1 and set `alarmTime.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time` in viewDidLoad

Comment: @amirt But this is not showing second. can we have to change something for it