# How to get the date from an UIDatePicker with mode set to Time only

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

My `UIDatePicker` needs to show only the time, but I also need to get the current date when that time was set.

Is this possible if the date picker has the `mode` set to `Time` ?

Currently I get this when I print the current date from date picker:

```
2000-01-01 3:00:00 AM +0000
```

Comment: Please check solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559172/trying-to-set-only-time-in-uidatepicker-in-swift-2-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current date creating a Date object "Date()", and you could use the "valueChanged" event to merge both values, the time they picked and the date you got